# Other things made from Banana nut bread

Tags: baking

I have 2 loaves of banana nut bread that are not quite baked completely(they are very dense with lots of banana). What other things could I make with them as I refuse to waste food??

Comment: I'd just try to cut into thin slices, then re-bake or toast in a toaster oven. (I do this with freshly-baked or slightly-stale banana bread also.) Are they so under-baked as to be completely inedible?

Answer (score 3):

You can make pretty much any bread-like substance into **french toast** (slice the bread, dip or soak in eggs mixed with a little milk, then shallow-fry in your choice of fat) or **bread pudding** (cube the bread, if necessary spread it out to dry and/or toast it, pile it in a baking pan, cover in a milk + egg + sweetening mixture, bake). Heck, if you're feeling really decadent (or you can't make up your mind), you can make **french toast bread pudding**: fry the bread, then make it into bread pudding.

Answer (score 1):

Would make awesome bread pudding.